# 2 tableview on a single view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need an example or explanations of how to populate 2 table views which are on the same view. I need to understand the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, could someone provide me an example on how should the code be?

I mean how to identify which goes which table view?

Thanks

Below is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

// Configure the cell...
// Set up the cell
MyAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (tableView == radios_tv) { //radio_tv is an IBOutleet UITableView
        sqlClass *aRadio = (sqlClass *)[appDelegate.array_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setText:aRadio.r_name];
        return cell;
    }
    if (tableView == presets_tv) { //preset_tv is an IBOutlet UITableView


    }

}
```

---

and hey vikingsegundo, now I need to delete a cell which is on my TableViewController class, how do I do this? I explain, here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

        //Delete the object from the table.
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Since we put different controllers, how should we proceed for this line? Should I put the tableViewController instead of the "self"?

```
//Delete the object from the table.
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMO the cleanest solution would be to have one controller for each tableview.

`radios_tv` would call it own delegate's method, while `presets_tv` calls it own.

**edit**

if you use one controller for n tableview, you will have to use if-statemenst in many places,
in

- `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`
- `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
- `– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`
- …

basically in all UITableViewDatasource-Protocol methods that you will need to implement.

So if you need to change something, you have to change it in many places.

If you use one controller class for one tableview, you won't have to check at all.

1. write a controller class for every tableview, make it conforming to the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol

   - implement the protocol methods you will need. at least

     - `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`,
     - `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`,
     - `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
2. call `-setDataSource:`for every tableview to an object of the right controller class

I think, it was shown in one of the [WWDC 2010 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). I am not sure, but I guess it was *Session 116 - Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS*.

**edit**

I wrote an example code: http://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples

Comment: and how do we do this? What do you mean by controller? Sorry, I'm quite a newbie :s

Comment: I am searching for an example right now. please stay tuned :)

Comment: thanks :D I've looked for an example too, but i've been unable to find any :(

Comment: I will try it tomorrow at work :D thank you very much vikingosegundo :D

Comment: sorry vikingosegundo, what do you mean by one controller for one tableview? could you provide an example please?

Comment: I mean that u have own Controller classes for the different TableViews, as this keeps u from doing to many if-statements

Comment: Hey Viking, I successfully adapted your code to my code, it helped a lot :D However I have one more question, how to make the cells selectable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On one view controller if you have to use two tables then you can set IBOutlet to both tables or assigns different tag to them so when you use following cellForRowAtIndexPath you can differentiate in both tables as below

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   

    UITableViewCellStyle style =UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier"; 
    DataListCell  *cell = (DataListCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 

    cell = [[DataListCell alloc]  initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        if(tableView==tblLanguage)//tblLanguage IBOutlet for first table
        {  
            if ((selectedIndexPath != nil) && (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row))
            {

                UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320-30, 9, 22, 15)];
                imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_Expand.png"];
                [cell addSubview:imgView];



                tblSongs.hidden=NO;
                tblSongs.frame=CGRectMake(0,42, 320, ([arrSongListForSpecificLanguage count]*40));
                [cell addSubview:tblSongs];
            }
            else 
            {
                UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320-30, 9, 16, 22)];
                imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_Collaps.png"];
                [cell addSubview:imgView];
            }


            cell.lblCustomerName.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            cell.lblCustomerName.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];




            //set the first label which is always a NamesArray object
            [cell setcustomerName:[objAppDelegate.viewController.arrLanguage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else //for other table
        {
            ParseData *objParse;
            objParse=[arrSongListForSpecificLanguage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



            cell.lblCustomerName.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            cell.lblCustomerName.frame=CGRectMake(cell.lblCustomerName.frame.origin.x, cell.lblCustomerName.frame.origin.y, 310, cell.lblCustomerName.frame.size.height);


            //set the first label which is always a NamesArray object
            [cell setcustomerName:objParse.track];

        }
        return cell;    
    }


}
```

You can also use tag for the same in which your if statement as below
if(tableView.tag==1)//tblLanguage tag=1

Similar if statement use for other delegate & datasource methods of table