# Static TableView and Dynamic Table view in same view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got a problem,

I need to have 2 tables views in the same view.

The first one have to be a static tableview and the second one dynamics.

The view should look like this

[image: The view should look like this]

[image]

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: what is the issue? you question seems like you are telling something not asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine static and prototype content in a table view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322885/combine-static-and-prototype-content-in-a-table-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static tableView **must** be embedded in a UITableViewController, which automatically expands it to the full available size, so you can not have another view within it.

However, you can accomplish what you are trying to do by using two dynamic table view's and embed them in a standard view controller.  You will have to make multiple prototype cells and return the appropriate cell based on which row is asked for instead of the static table view.

Answer (score 1):

Create two instances of UITableView and synthesize them. Set the delegate and datasource of both to self. Define the frames and add them to your view. Conform to UITableAViewDelegate. Them customize your tableview using the delegate methods

Comment: This will not work with a static table view.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: on static tableview call super tableviewdatasource and delegate methods,
 on dynamic tableview, return your own stuff

You have to check which tableview is the case in every tableviewdelegate and datasource function.

For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    //messagetableview is one with dynamic content
    if(tableView != messageTableview)
    {
        //super is called when static content is in case
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; 

    }
    else 
    {
       //return dynamic count
       return [conversation messagecount];
    }

}
```