# Add a new section in a static UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview, which is created within a storyboard. The cells contained inside are put as “Static cell”.

Now, I want to introduce a new section at the end of the tableview (i.e. so add some dynamic cells), and it's there that I cannot figure out how to do it.

Does anybody of you have an idea of how I can go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine static and prototype content in a table view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322885/combine-static-and-prototype-content)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return actualSection+1;
}
```

reloadData your table whenever you add new section with update `actualSection` or add object in array(which you are using for table)