# Creating a static "add" cell at index 0 of dynamic UITableView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have an app that adds Points of Interest (POIs) to a `managedObjectContext`. On the `AddPOITableViewController`, I have a segue that goes to a `CategoryTableViewController` and the `CategoryTVC` displays the existing categories in the `managedObjectContext`.

The navigation is as follows:

```
POIList-->AddPOIViewController-->CategoryTableViewController-->AddCategoryVC
```

**Problem:**
As I don't have any categories in the `managedObjectContext`, there are none displayed on my `CategoryTVC`.

**What I'd like to do:**
Create a special cell on `CategoryTVC` that segues to an `AddCategoryTVC` where I can create a new category in the `managedObjectContext`.

I know I'd need to add a special cell at `index[0]` that segues with I click. I'd like to drive that off the count of my `category.count`. I'd add the extra space for my special cell with `numberOfRowsInSection` (ex: `category.count+1`). For the segue to AddCategoryVC, I'd have to treat my "Add Category" cell differently (I'd make it `index[0]`)

Any ideas how I'd do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The indexPath object in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` callback tells you what cell was clicked. Simply check this object to see was it your "add category" cell, if so, perform the other segue. Like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == <myAddRowIndex>)
    {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AddCategorySegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pointOfInterestSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post helpful in getting my task done:

[Combine static and prototype content in a table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322885/combine-static-and-prototype-content-in-a-table-view)

In this situation, I'm essentially creating a static cell at indexPath.row[0] and the rest of the content is dynamic and pulled from the managedObjectContext.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
// Added this constant
#define NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS 1

// Added these properties
static NSString *DynamicIdentifier = @"DynamicIdentifier";
static NSString *StaticIdentifier = @"StaticIdentifier";

// Tweaked numberOfRowsInSection to add an extra cell
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.locationCategories.count + NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StaticIdentifier];

        // this sets up the static cell at the top
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:StaticIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Category";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return cell;

    } else {

        // this sets up the dynamic cells below
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DynamicIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Configure the cell...
        NSManagedObject *locationCategory = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [locationCategory valueForKey:@"categoryName"];

        if (locationCategory == self.category.categoryName) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

This is where the segue takes place to my `AddCategoryViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If there was a previous selection, unset the accessory view for its cell.
    NSManagedObject *currentCategory = self.category.categoryName;

    if (currentCategory != nil && indexPath.row > NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS - 1) {
        NSInteger index = [self.locationCategories indexOfObject:currentCategory];
        NSIndexPath *selectionIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectionIndexPath];
        checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    if (indexPath.row > NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS - 1) {
        // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        // Update the type of the location category instance
        self.category.categoryName = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Deselect row
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCategory" sender:nil];
        NSLog(@"addCategory segue fired from didSelectRowAtIndexPath method");
    }
}
```