# UITableView updates for correct number of managedObjects, but won't display values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `tableViewController` that displays an "Add" (static) cell at the top and I want it to list attributes of objects (dynamic cells) pulled from a `managedObjectContext`. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322885/combine-static-and-prototype-content-in-a-table-view) helpful in getting the "Add" cell working, but now that I've saved objects to to the `managedObjectContext`, I've discovered it doesn't display the attributes of the objects in the `managedObjectContext`.

To "see" what's going on, I made the "dynamic" cells orange. When I add categories to the `managedObjectContext`, the # of orange cells updates properly, but I can't get the attribute of my `managedObject` (an `NSString`) to display in the cell.

I threw a breakpoint in after my `fetchRequest` is completed to see if there are `LocationCategories` (my `NSManagedObject`) in the array--there are.

`CategoryTVC.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) LocationCategory *category;
```

`CategoryTVC.m`

```
    #define NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS 1 // this can be updated

    // Sets up an array to dump LocationCategories into
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *locationCategories;

    // cell identifier strings
    static NSString *DynamicIdentifier = @"DynamicIdentifier";
    static NSString *StaticIdentifier = @"StaticIdentifier";

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.title = @"Select a Category";

    // Core Data
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LocationCategory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"categoryName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSArray *categories = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    self.locationCategories = categories; // probably duplicate to line above, but modeling Apple's sample code
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:DynamicIdentifier];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:StaticIdentifier];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"";
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return @"Categories";
    } else {
        // This is just to shut up the compiler
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return self.locationCategories.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StaticIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:StaticIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Create new category";
        return cell;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DynamicIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:DynamicIdentifier];
        }

        NSManagedObject *locationCategory = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [locationCategory valueForKey:@"categoryName"];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; // TODO: Gives cell a color to see how many self.locationCategories there are
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I'm adding my LocationCategory class below:

```
**LocationCategory.h**
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class PointOfInterest;

@interface LocationCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id categoryColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *pointOfInterest;
@end

**LocationCategory.m**

#import "LocationCategory.h"
#import "PointOfInterest.h"

@implementation LocationCategory

@dynamic categoryColor;
@dynamic categoryName;
@dynamic pointOfInterest;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call reloadData on your table view after the fetch request (so the last line in viewWillAppear).

Also, when you register a class for your cells, there's no need for an if (cell==nil) clause because your cell will never be nil.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm tempted to delete this question, I'm going to leave it up in case someone else makes the same (stupid) mistake I made.

@rdelmar found an updating issue, which is resolved by adding the following line to `viewWillAppear` in `CategoryTVC.m`:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I have another ViewController called AddCategoryViewController with the following properties on it.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *categoryNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *categoryName;
```

When I saved the new LocationCategory, my save did this:

```
- (IBAction)saveCategory:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Save Button Clicked");
    NSError *error;
    error = nil;
    LocationCategory *newCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LocationCategory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newCategory.categoryName = self.categoryName; // THIS IS WRONG!!!!
    newCategory.categoryColor = self.categoryColor;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"AddCategoryViewController popped off");
}
```

The incorrect line above should be:

```
newCategory.categoryName = self.categoryNameTextField.text;
```

The net effect of my mistake was it dumped gibberish into my managedObjectContext and made it appear as though something was there for `self.locationCategories.count`'s purposes.